# How to detect which window is the foreground window?

Tags: c#, window, foreground

I need to write an assembly (C#.net 2.0 class library) to monitor all
applications
currently running in a PC. Especially, I need to know which window is the top
one, i.e., catch the event when a window becomes foreground window.  Should
I use WndProc() to catch related window messages? (I don't want
to use timer).

Any reference paper or sample source code? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want notifications, you need a [CBT Hook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644977(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: Not in .NET, no. I've used it myself in C++ many many years ago. But I bet Google does! :-)

Comment: I'm really obliged to do it in C++ ?

Comment: You can do it in C#, but I haven't done that myself, so I don't have any code.